# private[this] on mutable constructor parameter causing unexpected behavior

Tags: scala

When I run the code below,

```
class A(private[this] var i: Int) {
  println("i = " + i)
  i -= 1
  println("After decrement, i = " + i)

  override def toString = i.toString
}
object A extends App {
  val a = new A(1)
  println("a = " + a)
}
```

I get:

```
i = 1
After decrement, i = 0
a = 1
```

If I replace `private[this]` by `private`, I get the expected behavior, i.e. the last output line becomes `a = 0`. I'm using IntelliJ 2016.1.2, Scala plugin version 3.0.6., and scala-sdk-2.11.8.

Comment: Yes, I do get the same behavior. And no, I cannot explain it :(

Comment: I just tried this and it is an even weirder result: http://pastebin.com/fKCjnWVZ

Comment: @Martijn you got the opposite behavior, basically. It's probably due to the same bug, whose essence seems to be that the compiled code also has a local i whose existence is not transparent (see answers). In your code, you are changing this.i, which does not affect the local i of the compiled code.

Comment: @StephaneBersier SI-6165 is the original bug report, 6880 is a duplicate.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, but SI-6165 has a misleading title.

Comment: @StephaneBersier *private[this] var in class constructor disallows mutation* is misleading? I don't really think the name matters though, if you scroll down and see the actual reproduce, it's identical to your reproduce :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, as it doesn't disallow mutation. See Martijn's comment. Linking to both bugs can only improve your answer, don't you think?

Comment: @StephaneBersier Yes perhaps *disallow* is a poor choice for a description, but I think the example is concise. But, m-z's answer already points to 6880 so they can simply choose one :)

Comment: @StephaneBersier I guess you're right. Added 6880 as well :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112070/discussion-between-stephane-bersier-and-yuval-itzchakov).

Comment: I chose to link 6880 because the code example was a little more comprehensive with respect to showing the difference between `private[this]` and `private`, and resembled the code in the OP. The other issues can be found linked from 6880.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Heh, just came back to post that as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [it's a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37256564/1870803) ([SI-6165](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6165), [SI-6880](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6880)).

Let's explore further. This is the decompiled code for both cases:

`private[this]`:

```
class A extends Object {
  <paramaccessor> private[this] var i: Int = _;
  override def toString(): String = scala.Int.box(A.this.i).toString();
  def <init>(i: Int): com.yuval.A = {
    A.this.i = i;
    A.super.<init>();
    scala.this.Predef.println("i = ".+(scala.Int.box(i)));
    i = i.-(1);
    scala.this.Predef.println("After decrement, i = ".+(scala.Int.box(i)));
    ()
  }
};
```

Here, we see that `var i` is created for the object and is accessed *directly* in the code. We see that `i` is assigned to `A.this.i`, which is a direct assignment to the field. Later, **the mutated value is assigned to `i`, the method argument, not to `A.this.i`, the field of class `A`.** The actual value `i` is being shadowed.

On the contrary, when `i` is `private`:

```
class A extends Object {
  <paramaccessor> private[this] var i: Int = _;
  <accessor> <paramaccessor> private def i(): Int = A.this.i;
  <accessor> <paramaccessor> private def i_=(x$1: Int): Unit = A.this.i = x$1;
  override def toString(): String = scala.Int.box(A.this.i()).toString();
    def <init>(i: Int): com.yuval.A = {
      A.this.i = i;
      A.super.<init>();
      scala.this.Predef.println("i = ".+(scala.Int.box(A.this.i())));
      A.this.i_=(A.this.i().-(1));
      scala.this.Predef.println("After decrement, i = ".+(scala.Int.box(A.this.i())));
      ()
    }
};
```

Here, we see that `i` has a getter and setter methods, unlike `private[this]`. We also see that the decrement is being done on `A.this.i_`, which is the setter for the field member `A.this.i`.

Answer (score 8):

It's a bug. See [SI-6880](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6880).

`private[this]` on a constructor var causes it to mistakenly shadow itself, and you get the original value instead of the accessor you want.